# POST to sample URL for PayPal without "form"

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, curl, paypal

I am having some issue posting data to a specific URL when testing payment transactions on the paypal platform. Although much more technically understood, I chose not to use their API and NVP platform because of the requirement to FIRST create a transaction, then come back and have to create a recurring profile (as opposed to all at once - stupid design in my opinion).

Ultimately, I am trying to take data I have encrypted into a specific variable and post that data to a URL of choice WITHOUT having to treat it as a form where user clicks submit.

**My HTML form works** - the code is:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">';
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"/>';
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="'.$encrypted.'"/>';
<input type="submit" value="Go to checkout" name="submit" class="cartButton" />';
</form>
```

where $encrypted are my encrypted parameters. While the code works - I do not want to have the user click a link to be sent to the form. Instead, I want the user to click a button which first runs a PHP script to store the data in a temporary database THEN push the required elements (CMD and ENCRYPTED) to the post URL (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr).

Any ideas how to accomplish this? Is it possible? I use PHP and mySQL for my site. **Using Javascript of any kind is not a solution.**

## EDIT 1

I have it set up to use cURL as a possible way to POST the data but two things are happening: 1) I am getting no response whatsoever, 2) the consumer actually needs to be redirected to the paypal payment pages with the posted data after the database insert has taken place.

Comment: With an expresscheckout you can still get all data from the user, create a transaction, and then redirect the user to the paypal site. That you can go 'the long way around' (i.e. entering details in Paypal, go back to site, go back to Paypal) is not a necessity for flow. (And although it is officially required by paypal most expresscheckout implementations I have seen don't really bother with that ping-pong option).

Comment: I don't think PayPal like people doing it that way (Customers like payment pages to be secure and even if you did present the payment page through SSL, it would not show as a PayPal certificate). However, to go ahead anyway, you would need cURL or something that does the same job. Presenting the response you get back to your user should be straight forward. If you are getting no response at all, try posting to another site, if that fails, you may well be falling foul of a firewall rule (or be behind a NAT router).

Comment: @Wrikken - As I said above, the express checkout flow is HORRIBLE for recurring/subscription payments. Also - express checkout allows the consumer to make payment with PayPal balance - something we are not interested in at all.

Comment: @berty - I am not sure what you are saying. My "way" is the exact method somebody uses if they click an encrypted button I am already creating on my end. As I said in my edit, I am already using cUrl. I can already get my response back to the consumer so THAT is not the issue either. I find it hard to believe you read the question before posting several lines of comments and questions which dont apply or were already addressed.

Comment: not to mention - this is the supported and preferred way according to all PayPal guidelines. I don't collect any payment information up front - that is ALL handled on the Paypal end.

Comment: @JM4: sorry, missed the bit it was about subscriptions rather then 'one-off' payments. for which it is indeed ill-suited. cURL is definitely not a solution though, it just does no good for this purpose. You have to get the user to their pages, having the content of the page (which is all cURL will achieve) does not help with that. Someone might know a better subscription implementation (have you also checked the Paypal dev forums?), but it can  be your stuck with Paypal's flow, and as I said earlier: _'having a form post without click'_ & _'no javascript'_ are about mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its not possible but there is another way: you fire one asynchronous background javascript event that fires a post to your own server to store the data... and another synchronous foreground event that sends the form to PayPal for secure processing.

Comment: But, what about the users who disabled javascript in their browsers?

Answer (score 0):

You could use cURL to post data to the URL.

Comment: @chigley - I should have added my notes; only issue I have with cURL is that I actually need to consumer redirected to the posted URL as well with the posted data

Comment: @JM4 - in which case I can't really think of any suggestions that don't involve JavaScript! It may still be possible with cURL but I don't know enough about it to suggest anything.

Comment: It is indeed not possible to direct the user there with a cURL response (request is over & done), and without javascript this is impossible afaik. _'having a form post without click'_ & _'no javascript'_ are about mutually exclusive.

Comment: @wrikken - you are incorrect - posting form data and no javascript is quite easily achieved if simple post is all that is required. My issue however is that I need the data posted and the site redirected like a form action="".

Comment: POST's _never_ survive a redirect, it's in the specs. You can let a user do a GET request to a page, but _never_ a POST without using some kind of form. So if Paypal supports a GET url: fine. If they don't: you're out of luck with your requirements. And you are _never_ able te let _my_ browser perform a POST request without me clicking a button if I have javascript disabled. Ever.

Comment: @JM4: that is not _my_ browser, that is _your_ server doing the work / POST request, and hence, it will not work, because for the Paypal process to work, _my_ browser has to arrive with the POST values. Read up on your basics, I've heard my last _'you're incorrect'_ for the day from someone who not only doesn't understand the basics (which can happen, we all were once like that), but seems quite unwilling to learn despite turning to others for help. Good luck with that, and have a nice life.

Comment: @wrikken - I apologize if coming across as rude or "unwilling" to learn but from my perspective, this is a shining example of what  "inexperienced" programmers come across all the time. While the rules you speak of for PayPal may hold true, this was never once mentioned and reading something is "impossible" when it is not in principle. When I test on my local machine - a POST is occurring but I run into an error where the site thinks I need to log into the "sandbox"

Comment: 'a POST is occurring' indeed, I emphasizes "_my_" in "_my_ browser" for that reason. If you don't know something the correct response is not _'inccorect'_ (sic), which instantly makes me unwilling to progress any further. Long story short: in response to the POST request (that the browser of the user should perform, not your server), Paypal starts a session, stores values, sets all kind of cookies, which you can't get the users browser to send to paypal.com because cookies aren't shared across domains (in normal security setups for browsers).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered piping the data through `wget`?

Comment: Not really the solution i am looking for given the Paypal settings